# Performance Issue - Slow Compile Process

Tags: playframework-2.1

Guys... I'm using play framework for more than 3 month now... I wonder how to speed up compilation speed, because now there is 1072 Scala sources and 606 Java sources in my project and the compilation can take more than 5 minutes... It's really stress me out.... Is there any solution beside upgrading my hardware....?

FYI This is my hardware specification :
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 4000MB RAM
          Page File: 4615MB used, 3383MB available
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11

Comment: don't use playframework. i have been bitten once with slow compile times. basically there is nothing you can do even if you spend thousands on the hardware (very incremental change).

Comment: that's bad advice there. as @mguillermin says in his answer, there was a clear design problem with the single-module application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4GB of RAM is your bottleneck. 8GB is minimum, and only recently I've started working with 16GB which took the stress off me.

From what I see your OS is some MS Windows. Working under some Linux-like system would let you mount the `target` directory to RAM, thus speeding up the compilation, but that requires at least 16GB of RAM or working without graphical environment with less memory.

Comment: Are you still experiencing Out of Memory? Because after re-compile several time my project there will be Out of Memory PermGen space... i have increase it to -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M... but nothing really change...

Comment: @Raga Pinilih No, I don't have any OOM exceptions any more.

Comment: How about compiling time? my project has 1084 java and 602 scala and my compiling time is more than 900s... how about You with 16GB of ram?

Answer (score 4):

With such a high number of files, you should probably split your project into smaller modules.

The compilation will be more selectively triggered, and it will very more rarely need to compile the whole project.

You can find more information on how to create a multi-module project [in Working with Sub-Projects section of the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SBTSubProjects)

Comment: Well, if I start a new project i would start with split the project first...But this project almost complete, i think it will take more time to splitting this project...